# Programmatically added quote item Option [additional_options] showing in cart but not showing in order details on front and admin

Tags: magento2, cart, orders, custom-options, additional-information

I Am Creating Quote Item Option [additional_option] To Cart.

I Am Using This Code Base

```
    $item->addOption([
        'product' => $data['product'],
        'code'  => 'additional_options',
        'value' => serialize($this->additionalCart)
    ]);
    $item->saveItemOptions();
```

Product added in Cart Successfully Added With All My Options And Showing On Cart Page And MiniCart,

but After Checkout & Placing Order Additional Options Are Not Showing In **Admin->Sales->Order.**

Is There Something I Forgot To add?